# Remove white backgrounds from images

Tags: c, objective-c, cocoa, image-processing, image-manipulation

I have some product photos, from which I would like to remove the white background.
An example:

[image]
<sub>(source: [dewalt.at](http://www.dewalt.at/ProductImages/imports/EU_Images/Dewalt/573786_DC415N.jpg))</sub>

Is there a nice library or a manual way to do it with Cocoa or C?
For which keywords (image processing methods) do I have to search?

Comment: Several Apple apps have an inbuilt "Instant Alpha" feature. Would appreciate if you'd also file a radar bug requesting 3rd party access to the API for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try ImageMagick:

```
convert input.gif -transparent white output.gif
```

For more advanced features you should try something like image masking or do it manually using any image library, setting the pixel values to something with a high alpha value.

See also this thread: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=10665

Comment: using gif will create jagged edges, however using imagmajick is a good answer nonetheless, just use PNG output though and allow a bit of anti-aliasing at the edge colors.

Comment: Also, ImageMagick has bindings for nearly every language, so you can use the ImageMagick library from within C